# How do I run a Google Apps script on all sheets in my spreadsheet file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**PROBLEM**:

I've seen similar questions and solutions but **can only get my script to run on the first sheet** in my Spreadsheet file. I've adapted the code from only applying on a specific sheet, but maybe I've missed something when I was doing that..

The code:

```
/** 
 * Sets background color to strikethrough-formatted cells
 */
function set_color_strikethrough(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[i];  // current sheet
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    console.log("sheetname: ", sheetName);
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc);
    var results = range.getFontLines();

    for (var i=0;i<lr;i++) {
      for (var j=0;j<lc;j++ ) {
        if(results[i][j] == "line-through"){
          var color = sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,lc).setBackground("orange")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE (solution)**:

Thanks to @Tanaike for pointing out that the `i` counter variable was misused, a simple mistake that was overlooked.
Working code:

```
/** 
 * Sets background color to strikethrough-formatted cells
 */
function set_color_strikethrough(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (k=0; k<sheets.length; k++) {
    var sheet = sheets[k];  // current sheet
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc);
    var results = range.getFontLines();

    for (var i=0;i<lr;i++) {
      for (var j=0;j<lc;j++ ) {
        if(results[i][j] == "line-through"){
          var color = sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,lc).setBackground("orange")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Your title says `I run a Google Apps script on all sheets in my spreadsheet file`. Your question says `I've adapted the code from only applying on a specific sheet`. Can I ask you about your goal? 2. Can I ask you about the issue of your script?

Comment: I'm running the script yet it only applies on the first sheet in my Spreadsheet file. My goal is for it to apply on all sheets in the document.

Comment: You got the title wrong, the `How do I..` makes all the difference. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the relationship between `I've adapted the code from only applying on a specific sheet` and your script?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm happy to get help. :)

The original code is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153409/google-spreadsheet-colour-rows-if-strikethrough

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason of your issue is that the for loop using `i` is used in the for loop using `i`. And `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[i];` can be modified to `var sheet = sheets[i];`. So how about modifying `for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {var sheet = sheets[i];` to `for (k=0; k<sheets.length; k++) {var sheet = sheets[k];`?

Comment: Yes of course! the reused `i` variable was the problem.. I feel stupid now for not seeing that earlier.. thank you so much for the help. Can you please formulate it as an answer and I will mark it as the valid answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer by including more information. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to modify as follows.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the for loop using the variable of `i` is used in the for loop using `i`. `i` at the 1st for loop is changed by the 2nd for loop. By this, the loop using `i` doesn't correctly work as you expect. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[i];` can be modified to `var sheet = sheets[i];`. By this, the process cost can be reduce a little.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function set_color_strikethrough(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (k=0; k<sheets.length; k++) {  // <--- Modified
    var sheet = sheets[k]; // <--- Modified
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    console.log("sheetname: ", sheetName);
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc);
    var results = range.getFontLines();

    for (var i=0;i<lr;i++) {
      for (var j=0;j<lc;j++ ) {
        if(results[i][j] == "line-through"){
          var color = sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,lc).setBackground("orange")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```